# Possible to avoid boxing and unboxing for Lambda using Class::method syntax? (Java)

Tags: java, lambda, primitive

I've recently stumbled upon the `Class::method` syntax which allows you to insert lambda code which from a static method like this:

```
public class Main {

  public static void foo(int foo) {
    System.out.println(foo);
  }

  public static void bar(Consumer<Integer> bar) {
    bar.accept(1);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    bar(Main::foo);
  }

}
```

The question is, does boxing and unboxing of 1 still occur? After all, `bar`'s parameter is a `Consumer<Integer>` which should normally box primitives, yet `foo(int)` is a method which accepts a primitive, thus boxing is not neccessary.

So, what happens? Does `1` get turned into an `Integer` or does it remain primitive?

On a side note, I am aware that `IntConsumer` delivers a solution to get rid of boxing and unboxing, but not every single functional interface has an alternative for every single primitive type, hence the question.

Comment: If you are in a situation where you are free to choose between Consumer<Integer> and IntConsumer, it is likely you are also free to create your own functional interfaces that use primitive types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is boxed and then unboxed.

Compiling the code and then decompiling the class file reveals the following:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void foo(int foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

    public static void bar(Consumer<Integer> bar) {
        bar.accept(Integer.valueOf(1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bar(Main::foo);
    }
}
```

The compiler automatically boxes 1, meaning it will be unboxed when foo() is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The answer is quite disappointing though.

Answer (score 2):

If the answer you accepted surprises you, than because you don't know enough about Java yet. So don't call it a disappointment, but a *disillusion*.

In contrast to C++ templates Java generics work with for reference types **only**.

Thus there is absolutely **no** way any generic-using construct can directly work with primitive types! So whenever you use a primitive type value in such a context, it **must** be boxed.

Maybe, one day far in the future, when the parents of Java decide to redo generics, that might change, but we are not there yet.

Comment: Well, in this very specific scenario it would actually be possible to create a `Consumer<Integer>` that also accepts primitives since it originated from a static method that does accept one primitive int.

This method may not be visible when writing up code but could be available during runtime.

Comment: Sure, but **method overloading** only works when both; "client" and "provider" are aware of this special case. And you couldn't call it a `Consumer<Integer` anymore; you would have to use a specific class then; or worse: do  type check within the method and a downcast. And then, you would have **two** accepts methods in your Consumer ... what would they do?! Duplicate code there? In other words: I would be really curious about the usefulness of code coming out of such ideas.

Comment: Project Valhalla (value types) will fix a lot of this, but not right now. It's Java 10ish.

Comment: @Markus Hopefully Java 10ish. Me heard people talking about value types when working on my master thesis (added a "primitive type" for complex numbers back then) ... that was 1997. So I am not holding my breath on this ;-)