# Why autoboxing does not work with Predicate

Tags: java, predicate, autoboxing

I have this code:

```
System.out.println(test( (int i) -> i == 5) ); // Error here

System.out.println(test( (Integer i) -> i == 5) ); // No error here

private static boolean test(Predicate<Integer> p) {
  return p.test(5);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean “why”? What kind of answers are you looking for? Quotes from the language specification perhaps? Or something else?

Comment: I'd assume the OP wants a quote from the JLS, so they can look at that section and understand lambda currying (or whatever this is) better and how to predict it.  I'm interested too.  Why does autoboxing in a lambda like this sometimes work and sometimes not?  Here's an example where the autoboxing appears to work, why is it different? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303074/possible-to-avoid-boxing-and-unboxing-for-lambda-using-classmethod-syntax-ja

Comment: Autoboxing only works if it's implicit what type should be boxed or unboxed.  You've made it explicit.

Comment: Explicit here `Predicate<Integer>`, test wants a Predicate for an Integer (object), and as primitive types cannot be used as generic, only the reference type can be used here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That makes sense, I tested it as `test((i) -> i == VAL + 1)` on my system (Java 21) and it also compiles and runs.

Comment: maybe [JLS 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3)

Comment: Please explicitly include the resulting error in your question.